# How to correctly animate view slide UP & slide Down after onFling event?

Tags: android, animation, view, onfling, yaxis

I spend several hours by trying to animate view slide UP, slide Down based on the finger direction. I am able to fire onFling event on the custom view and get direction of the finger movement using

```
 @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Logger.d("onFling "+ velocityY);
        if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {
            Logger.d("Bottom to top");
            slideView(velocityY, e1, e2, Constants.Global.MOVE_BOTTOM_TOP);
            return false; // Bottom to top
        }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {
            Logger.d("Top to bottom");
            slideView(velocityY, e1, e2, Constants.Global.MOVE_TOP_BOTTOM);
            return false; // Top to bottom
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I tried to do fling animation using the FlingAnimation:

```
 FlingAnimation flingAnimation = new FlingAnimation(viewGroup, DynamicAnimation.TRANSLATION_Y); // moves the view on the x-axis
        // derive the pixelPerSecond with start velocity value
        float pixelPerSecond = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, motionEvent1.getY(), getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        flingAnimation
            .setStartVelocity(pixelPerSecond)
            .setMinValue(motionEvent1.getRawY())
            .setMaxValue(toYDelta)
            .setFriction(0.8f)
            .start();
```

or using the `TranslateAnimation` or `SlideOutUpAnimator` from the following library:
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations

Unfortunately, the slideout animation of the view is still not working correctly.

The view can be positioned in Y-axis using the processing in onScroll event:

```
@Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        Logger.d("onScroll distanceX: "+distanceX+" distanceY: "+distanceY);
        params.y = initialY + (int) (e2.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
        params.x = 0;
        windowManager.updateViewLayout(view, params);
        return false;
    }
```

**OnScroll** positioning works great, but I still have a problem to animate slideout to bottom or top. I think that is based on the wrong processing of root view which should be positioned too.

Could someone experienced with animations on the views provide some example how should be slideout animation on Y-axis done in the right way, please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: It throws   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Starting value need to be in between min value and max value

I don't know what values pass to 

.setMinValue(motionEvent1.getRawY())
.setMaxValue(3000)

Should it be values from view, motion event? I thought that I should to pass into minValue actual position of view and to maxValue position on Y axis where I want to animate. Fx. the animation is from top to bottom, start value is actual position of the view, the end is set to 3000, which means that view should not be visible on the screen.

Comment: Yes, but passing pixelPerSecond or velocityY to setStartVelocity does not work, it throws the exception. Could You please provide an example which is working for you with values provided by params given by callback method?.

Comment: I saw Your pastebin and I removed min and max values. Exception is gone, but I think that problem will be in onScroll method. I replaced method update windowManager.updateViewLayout(viewGroup, params); by onScroll which i found in Your code. Seems to be smoother now than before but scroll methos does not actualize parent layout position.

See please my pastebin https://pastebin.com/XymnhPHJ